# NullReferenceException on object initialized with FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

I'm mocking out a DbContext, and in my tests I want to ensure entities are marked for being deletion. As I mark each object in my mocked context, I track each entity with a static Dictionary:

```
public DbEntityEntry<T> Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    var entry = (DbEntityEntry<T>)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(DbEntityEntry<T>));

    var state = entityStates[entity];
    entry.State = state;

    return entry;
}

public void SetEntityState(object entity, System.Data.EntityState state)
{
    entityStates.Add(entity, state);
    Entry(entity).State = state;
}

private static Dictionary<object, EntityState> entityStates = new Dictionary<object, EntityState>();
```

I couldn't get the `DbEntityEntry` instantiated with `Activator.CreateInstance()`, so I've instantiated with `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()`.

The issue is this line:

```
entry.State = state;
```

Trying to assign to this property results in:

```
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Obviously the object isn't initialized given the name of the function, but I'm unsure why I can't assign to the object's properties without throwing this exception.

FWIW, the test looks something like:

```
 TripManager.DeleteTripsByForeignKey(int carId);

 var trip1 = _fakeDbContext.Trips.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TripId == 1);

 var entry = _fakeDbContext.Entry(trip1);

 Assert.AreEqual(EntityState.Deleted, entry.State);
```

Comment: `entry == null;` is returning `false`. But all of the entry's properties throw the NRE. I'm wondering why I can't assign to those properties.

Comment: Likewise, `entry.ToString()` produces: "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1[System.Object]"

Comment: You would have to look at the property setters to see why you can't call them. Most likely, they depend on internal state which is null.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ah, you are of course correct. The setter is: `set { _internalEntityEntry.State = value; }`, so obviously `_internalEntityEntry` is null.

Answer (score 0):

`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` doesn't call any constructor on the type. That means that fields that have default values or are set in the constructor don't get set. If you look at the definition for the `State` property (https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/DbEntityEntry.cs - forgive the link to the mono version), you can see that the setter depends on `_internalEntityEntry`, which is set in the constructor:

```
internal DbEntityEntry(InternalEntityEntry internalEntityEntry)
{
    _internalEntityEntry = internalEntityEntry;
}
```

this is, of course, why you shouldn't be messing around with `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` :)

If you really know what you're doing, you could call the internal constructor explicitly and mock the `InternalEntityEntry` as well...but this seems like a really bad idea.